useMediaQuery does not work in top level React component but works in child component
When I use useMediaQuery from Material UI in my React app in the top level component (App) of my app, the query doesn't work (value doesn't update on window resize) and causes rendering issues (when using Chrome's dev tools mobile screen emulators). But if I move the query in to a child component (AppContainer), it works. Is it because the containing component needs to have some kind of size attributes?
Here is my top level component with the query:
import firebase from './firebase/Firebase';
import {useState} from "react";
import {AuthContext} from "./contexts/AuthContext";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";

function App() {

    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const isWideScreen = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 500px)', {noSsr: true});

    firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (userObject) => {
        setIsLoggedIn(!!userObject);
        if (userObject){
            await localStorage.setItem('accessToken', await userObject.getIdToken());
        }
        setUser(userObject);
    })

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn , user }}>
            <>
                <span>{'isWideScreen:'+ isWideScreen.toString()}</span>
            </>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );

}

export default App;

Update: I have found that if I COMMENT OUT the firebase auth onIdTokenChanged line of code, the media query works. But if I keep the firebase auth code in this component, the media query fails to update on resize.

I'm unable to reproduce. Maybe the problem happens where you try to access ScreenContext. Can you show the code that calls useContext(ScreenContext)?

I've verified that the context provider is not the issue. Even if I remove the context and use this as my App.js, the value of isWideScreen does not update on window resize in Chrome dev tools mobile screen emulator. I will update the original post with my code.

@NicholasTower See my update to the post. I have added in the firebase code that seems to be causing the issue.

Try putting that entire firebase code block inside of a useEffect that runs once on mount.  The effect will handle adding the onIdTokenChanged event handler to the firebase object.  The callback function will still run every time that the user changes in firebase.

What I'm seeing here is that you have some wonky stuff relating to the Firebase setup.  I can't say for sure that this will fix your MUI problems, but I would give it a try.
You only need to set the onIdTokenChanged handler for your Firebase instance one time.  The callback function will still run every time that the id token is changed.  You should do this inside of a useEffect hook with an empty dependency array [] to run this once at mount (you could use dependencies [setIsLoggedIn, setUser] and it will behave the same, as these functions never change).
The await inside of localStorage.setItem is confusing.  I would move this to a separate line.  You do not need to await localStorage.setItem because that is a synchronous operation.
Try this:
import firebase from './firebase/Firebase';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from './contexts/AuthContext';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';

function App() {

    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const isWideScreen = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 500px)', { noSsr: true });

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (userObject) => {
            setIsLoggedIn(!!userObject);
            setUser(userObject);
            if (userObject) {
                const token = await userObject.getIdToken();
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn, user }}>
            <>
                <span>{'isWideScreen:' + isWideScreen.toString()}</span>
            </>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );

}

export default App;


As @LindaPaiste suggested, moving the firebase auth handler code into a useEffect fixed the media query issue.
    useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (userObject) => {
        setIsLoggedIn(!!userObject);
        if (userObject){
            await localStorage.setItem('accessToken', await userObject.getIdToken());
        }
        setUser(userObject);
    });
},[])

